# Is there any alternative expression to “Brace Yourself ”

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I have translated an article into English. The author of the original article uses a “Bumpy ride on a plane in a hazardous weather” as an analogy to predict an unfavourable  political development in a certain location. He advised the citizens there should “sit tight” (a literal translation here) and be prepared.

I could have translated the phrase *sit tight* as *brace yourself*, but it would lose the mental picture of the analogy. Besides, *sit tight* means something entirely different in English:  to be patient and await the next move.  It’s not a good idea to use *sit tight* to mean *brace yourself*.

So, is there any alternative phrase to *brace yourself* that conveys the same meaning while retaining the picture of the original phrase?

Comment: related: [What does ‘Brace yourself’ really mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9474/what-does-brace-yourself-really-mean)

Comment: Hmm... is winter coming?

Comment: @Yawus Yes, Lord Stark, we know: ***Winter is coming.***

Comment: @Yawus,tchrist Oh, the mime :-)

Comment: As an aside, "sit tight" does not suggest patience.

Comment: @Pantalones Most dictionaries say so

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would think *brace yourself* is exactly what you do when expecting turbulence, physical or metaphorical.  But you could try *hold tight* (or *hold on tightly*, depending on how formal the context is).

Comment: I think you're probably right. The English readers will find  the expression 'brace yourself' fits well in the context; it is me who should let go of the 'mental picture' :-)

Comment: I agree.  Brace yourself is perfect here.

Answer (score 4):

The term **hang on tight** is often used in conjunction with reference to a *bumpy ride*, both literally and figuratively.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the analogy you could use the usual airline instruction ***"Brace positions, please!"***

Answer (score 3):

How about “fasten your seat belts”?

Comment: LOL This phrase is good in certain contexts. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could say 'steel yourself' or 'prepare yourself'.